# value change in crystal report

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, report

In chart account table

```
glaccount  nametext 
1204005     BAH - Khay  
2202013     Sales Tax Payable New 
2019384    Generator
1848485    Vechicle
```

and in other table

this glaccount is in account table and this glaccount is unique values

```
 acdocno               glaccount  docamount   glnametxt
 0600000307             1204005     363538      BAH - Khay  
 0600000307             2202013     56003       Sales Tax Payable New   
 0600000307             1201001     456023      Accounts Receivable 
 0600000307             1201001     456023      Accounts Receivable 
  0600000307            1206004     36482       Adv Income Tax -
```

except 1204005 all glacct is fixed  only 1204005 is change when acdocno change

so how i get this glaccount amount i.e. 363538 in crystal report.. when i only drag field docamout then 456023 is displayed and i want this value 363538

current data in report

```
Acdocno    Total Amount  Bank Amount   Bank Name    
0600000307 456,023.00    456,023.00    Accounts Receivable
```

and i want

```
Acdocno      Total Amount  Bank Amount   Bank Name  
0600000307   456,023.00    363538       BAH - Khay
```

query which i tried

```
select distinct 
acdocdtl.acdocno,

acdocdtl.docamount,glchaact.glnamestxt
from acdocdtl
    inner join acdochdr 
    on 
     acdocdtl.acdocno =acdochdr.acdocno 
     and acdocdtl.cocode=acdochdr.cocode       

    left join glchaact  
    on acdocdtl.glacct = glchaact.glacct
    and acdocdtl.chaact=glchaact.chaact
where acdocdtl.acdocno='0600000307'
```

how i done this

Comment: you haven't provided table names and column names.. provide those difficult to understand queries

Comment: i already paste query

Comment: what is this table `acdocdtl, acdochdr, glchaact`... 3 tables?

Comment: glaccount  i.eg. glaact field is in acdocdtl and glchaact table and in acdochdr acdocno foreign key relationship

Comment: joins looks correct where did you place the fields in report and also when you run the same query on database how many records are you able to see and are you able to see the record that you wish for